# c++ assign char values (by using stack pop) to char*

Tags: c++, char

I am trying to reverse a char* by using a stack.

```
stack<char> scrabble;
char* str = "apple";

while(*str)
{
    scrabble.push(*str);
    str++;
    count++;
}

while(!scrabble.empty())
{
     // *str = scrabble.top();
     // str++;
     scrabble.pop();
}
```

In the second While-loop, I'm not sure how to assign each char from the stack's top to the char* str.

Comment: Shouldn't you just iterate over it backwards and copy it into a new buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. When you have a string defined using

   ```
   char* str = "apple";
   ```

   you are not supposed to change the value of the string. Changing such a string causes undefined behavior. Instead, use:

   ```
   char str[] = "apple";
   ```
2. In the while loops, use an index to access the array instead of incrementing `str`.

   ```
   int i = 0;
   while(str[i])
   {
       scrabble.push(str[i]);
       i++;
       count++;
   }

   i = 0;
   while(!scrabble.empty())
   {
      str[i] = scrabble.top();
      i++;
      scrabble.pop();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that "apple" is a const char[].

Answer (score 2):

You can also iterate a pointer to the `char[]` if you'd like

```
char str[] = "apple";

char* str_p = str;
int count = 0;

while(*str_p)
{
    scrabble.push(*str_p);
    str_p++;
    count++;
}

// Set str_p back to the beginning of the allocated char[]
str_p = str;

while(!scrabble.empty())
{
     *str_p = scrabble.top();
     str_p++;
     scrabble.pop();
}
```